# What's the definition/example of an exception which cannot be handled (outside of framework exceptions)?

Tags: c#, exception

As it is said that an exception should only be caught if it can be handled, what is an example of an exception which cannot be handled (outside of things like OOM, BadImageFormat, etc).

I'm under the impression that an exception which is logged is an exception that has been handled, or does handling mean doing some sort of corrective action (e.g. if a network share is down, try a backup share or mount another, etc)?

Examples of exceptions which can and can't be handled greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling (to me) means taking appropriate action to resume the flow of your application.  If you rethrow the exception, then you haven't handled it.  Logging would be one case where you might rethrow an exception.

An example of a exception that can be handled: you are running a service that notifies a particular user of an event.  You try to use a web service to send a SMS message, this gives an exception (server down, account closed, whatever), so as a fallback you send an email message, that fails with another exception, so you fall back to trying to make a voice call.  That succeeds and your customer gets notified of whatever he wanted to know.

An example of an exception that can sometimes be handled and other times not: you get an System Insufficient memory exception.  Sometimes you know that you have a lock on something that is large but non-critical, which you could release and then retry, but typically everything that you have an active reference to is something that must have, in which case there's nothing you can really do to recover.

Note that quite frequently, handling means simply returning false for a function that was asked to do something and for which a success/failure is returned.  This isn't as useless as it might at first appear, consider this scenario: you make a change to a file, and then tell the application to save the changes.   The disk is full or unavailable for some reason.  Either will cause an exception.  When saving you have isDirty = savefile() , the exception happens inside savefile and is "handled" by savefile by setting the result to false.  This allows the application to know (and to show to the user) that the file hasn't been saved.

Comment: So it's basically corrective action, not just logging to aid the people who debug the issue, so that the app can continue. Lesson would be to always ensure there are options (if one thing fails, there is a backup plan).

Comment: @dotnetdev: Broadly speaking. There are two things you do NOT want to do.  First you don't want the application to crash and burn (blue screen, application didn't handle exception, whatever) and secondly you don't want this to cause false results down stream. Sometimes you'll want to try a backup plan, sometimes you'll want to back out of what you're attempting, sometimes you can continue because it's acceptable for that not to succeed.  Logging exceptions is a developer extra for the most part, not a user benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the key framework exceptions which cannot be caught by the CLR (StackOverflow, OutOfMemory, etc) there are several exceptions that generally should not be caught as they represent developer errors that should be addressed during development. While logging the exceptions can be seen as a mechanism to "handle" the exception, it's only useful if the log files are reviewed for errors.

In general, exceptions like ArgumentNullException, ArgumentException, NullReferenceException, etc should not be caught by developers explicitly, and should be allowed to bubble up so that they can be identified and fixed.

Comment: Is there a circumstance where handling normal exceptions like DirectoryDoesNotExist could be handled and other circumstances where the same exception type thrown by the same code or different code may not be in a state to be handled? For example, handling the exception may involve trying a backup drive, but if this does not exist, the exception may not be in a state to be handled.

Comment: @dotnetdev: sure. And you're example is a nice example as to why you may not be able to handle the exception.  If the action that you would take in order to handle the excepton can't be done (either throws it's own exception or somehow returns false), you are left with either rethrowing the exception or creating your own exception to report that there was an exception and that the alternative was unsuccessful.